# Which word shoud I use: "designated," " fixed," or "certain"?

Tags: word-choice

Some schools regulate even shoes and bags of their school uniform.

How can I explain the situation? Which sentence is appropriate here:

> "We have to wear designated shoes."
>
> "We have to wear fixed shoes."
>
> "We have to wear certain shoes."?

Comment: Not being native, I would think of *particular*. "to wear particular shoes" sounds off though. - Another idea: *uniform*. "to wear uniform shoes".

Comment: "Particular" sounds good to me.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context, a word that is often used is "regulation."

"We have to wear **regulation** shoes, uniforms, schoolbags" etc.

The word form, "regulation" is short for "per regulation."

Answer (score 0):

*Designated* is used as in the following sentences.

> This area has been designated as a National Park.

> This floor has been designated a no-smoking area.

I can imagine, for example, a representative of the school showing a pair of shoes and saying "We designed these shoes as 'shoes of the school uniform'." but that probably would be a *stretchy* way to use *designed*.

*Certain* is used to, "mention a particular thing, person or group without giving any more details about it or them."

> Certain people might disagree with this.

*Certain shoes* would not say anything about the school wanting specific shoes.

I would rather say "We have to wear shoes approved by the school." since one of the meaning of *approve* is, "to say that something is good enough to be used or is correct."